# Hex to / from datetime stamp

Tags: date, datetime, hex, date-conversion

I've an application running on Windows, I don't have the source code, the GUI presents the date as 22/06/2018 08:44, this date/time is written/read from a file. This file contains a Hex representation of the date, some examples below (the latter two have been edited by myself - hence the weird year).

```
2C 05 0A D4 01 (22/06/2018 08:44)
2C 06 0A D4 01 (22/06/2018 08:51)
2C 08 11 D4 01 (01/07/2018 06:53)
B4 AE 08 D4 01 (06/12/5671 13:13)
B4 AE 11 12 10 (31/07/5270 10:53)
```

I'm trying to understand the conversion from Hex to the GUI date/time, so that I could modify the Hex in the file direct and see the GUI date/time accordingly

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: The hex numbers are standard Windows 64-bit values representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601, with the three least significant bytes omitted and written as little endian (least significant byte first). For example, your first hex string, 2C 05 0A D4 01, means hex 01D4 0A05 2C00 0000 units at 100 nanos since January 1, 1601 UTC (this is precisely 22/06/2018 08:44:02.9898752 UTC, but your GUI omits seconds and fraction of second).

You can read more [here: File Times on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx).

For the conversion from date and time to hex you may for example use http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=2018-06-22T08%3A44%3A00%2B00%3A00&inputformat=text, enter your date as 2018-06-22T08:44:00+00:00 and get the hex out as 01D40A05:2A37C800. Round up so it ends in three zero bytes: 01D40A05:2B000000. Reorder the remaining bytes: 2B 05 0A D4 01.

**Original answer**

It’s not a date-time encoding scheme that I have met before. And from the data you have provided I am not able to deduct the full scheme. I believe I have found a bit of the scheme. I cannot get further.

Assuming some linear correspondence I first note by comparing the first two samples that a difference of 1 unit of the second group of hex digits (the second byte if you will) makes for a difference of 7 minutes. Or approximately: we don’t know if the times have seconds and maybe even fractions of seconds that are not displayed.

I used this information when comparing to the third sample. The third byte has increased by 7 from the first to the third sample (hex 11 - hex 0A = 7). Taking the increase on the second byte into account it would seem that one unit of the third byte approximates 1832 minutes, which is suspiciously close to 256 * 7 minutes = 1792 minutes. So it would seem that the 2nd and 3rd bytes have a “little endian” relationship, where the 3rd byte is more significant than the 2nd. Using this information we can obtain a little more accuracy: The difference in the times is 12849 minutes, and the difference on the 2nd and 3rd byte is hex 1108 - 0A05 = decimal 1795, so each unit is 7.1582 minutes (it agrees with the 7 minutes from before, only it’s more precise). Using this value I interpolated the second date-time from the hex value 2C 06 0A D4 01 and got 2018-06-22T08:51:09. It agrees. Hypothesis confirmed!

The information found so far suffices for encoding values between 09/06/2018 14:43 (2C 00 00 D4 01) and 01/05/2019 09:17 (2C FF FF D4 01) with a precision of 7 minutes. I’d be surprised if that were enough for you.

Comparing to the value in the 4th sample it would seem that one unit on the first byte corresponds to 14 128 940 minutes (26.86 years). It doesn’t divide nicely by the 7.1582 minutes from before, as we might have hoped, so I’m not sure how we might use this observation.

Comparing the last two samples it seems that the 4th and 5th byte cannot have the same little endian relationship since the 5th byte increases while the date decreases. It’s still possible, though, if we assume that at least one of the years is before the common era (“BC”) since era is not printed. Another possibility might be that the fifth byte is ignored. This leads to a unit of the fourth byte corresponding to 1 088 006 minutes. Again it bears no nice relationship to the 7.15 minutes from bytes 2 and 3, and it’s suspicously close to the unit of the first byte, so probably incorrect.

To learn more: First try to see if you get a meaningful date-time from editing (hex) 00 00 00 00 00 into your file. If you do, next try one F at a time:

```
F0 00 00 00 00
0F 00 00 00 00
…
00 00 00 00 0F
```

If this doesn’t make a pattern that is clear enough, try one bit at a time, using hex digits 1, 2, 4 and 8 instead of F.

Comment: I made a mistake B4 AE 08 D4 01 (06/12/5671 13:13) should be 20/06/2018 15:52

Comment: Thanks. Now it all agrees. The hex numbers are 10 digit little endian numbers and denote time since an epoch at new year 1601. If only you could have given me the correct correspondence from the outset…

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how to accept the answer. Again, thanks for your help